# How to know if a BigDecimal can exactly convert to float or double?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Class `BigDecimal` has some useful methods to guarantee lossless conversion:

- `byteValueExact()`
- `shortValueExact()`
- `intValueExact()`
- `longValueExact()`

However, methods `floatValueExact()` and `doubleValueExact()` do not exist.

I read the OpenJDK source code for methods `floatValue()` and `doubleValue()`.  Both appear to fallback to `Float.parseFloat()` and `Double.parseDouble()`, respectively, which may return positive or negative infinity.  For example, parsing a string of 10,000 9s will return positive infinity.  As I understand, `BigDecimal` does not have an internal concept of infinity.  Further, parsing a string of 100 9s as `double` gives `1.0E100`, which is not infinity, but loses precision.

What is a reasonable implementation `floatValueExact()` and `doubleValueExact()`?

I thought about a `double` solution by combining `BigDecimal.doubleValue()`, `BigDecial.toString()`, `Double.parseDouble(String)` and `Double.toString(double)`, but it looks messy.  I want to ask here because there may (must!) be a simpler solution.

To be clear, I don't need a high performance solution.

Comment: I guess you could transform to double, then transform back the double to BigDecimal, and see if you obtain the same value. Not sure what's the use case is though. If you use doubles, you already accept to have non-exact values. If you want exact values, then stay with BigDecimal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [reading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#intValueExact--) [the](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#longValueExact--) [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#shortValueExact--), all it does with the `numTypeValueExact` variants is to check for existence of a fraction part or if the value is too big for the numeric type and throw exceptions.

As for [**`floatValue()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#floatValue--) and [**`doubleValue()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#doubleValue--), a similar overflow check is being done, but instead of throwing an exception, instead it returns `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` or `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` for doubles and `Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY` or `Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` for floats.

Therefore the most reasonable (and simplest) implementation of the `exact` methods for float and double, should simply check if the conversion returns `POSITIVE_INFINITY` or `NEGATIVE_INFINITY`.

---

*Furthermore*, remember that `BigDecimal` was designed to handle the lack of precision that comes from using `float` or `double` for large irrationals, therefore as [@JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) [*commented*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123861/how-to-know-if-a-bigdecimal-can-exactly-convert-to-float-or-double/59124029#comment104476779_59123861), another check you can add to the above would be to convert the `double` or `float` back to `BigDecimal` to see if you still get the same value. This should prove the conversion was correct.

Here is what such a method would look like for `floatValueExact()`:

```
public static float floatValueExact(BigDecimal decimal) {
    float result = decimal.floatValue();
    if (!(Float.isNaN(result) || Float.isInfinite(result))) {
        if (new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(result)).compareTo(decimal) == 0) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    throw new ArithmeticException(String.format("%s: Cannot be represented as float", decimal));
}
```

---

*The use of [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-) instead of [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) above is intentional so as to not become too strict with the checks. `equals` will only evaluate to true when the two `BigDecimal` objects have the same value and scale (size of the fraction part of the decimal), whereas `compareTo` will overlook this difference when it does not matter. For example `2.0` vs `2.00`.*

Comment: Very crafty.  Exactly what I needed!  Note: You may also wish to use `Float.isFinite()` or `Float.isInfinite()`, but this is optional. `:)`

Comment: You should also prefer compareTo over equals, because equals() in BigDecimal will consider 2.0 and 2.00 as different values.

Comment: Values that cannot be precisely represented as float will not work.  Example: `123.456f`.  I guess this is due to different size of significand (mantissa) between 32-bit float and 64-bit double.  In your above code, I get better results with: `if (new BigDecimal(result, MathContext.DECIMAL32).equals(decimal)) {`.  Is this a reasonable change... or am I missing another corner case of floating point values?

Comment: @kevinarpe - `123.456f` is conceptually the same as your 1.0E100 example.  It strikes me that if you *need* to check that the conversion from BigDecimal -> binary floating point is exact then *that need* is the problem; i.e. the conversion should not be contemplated.

Comment: You must use isFinite() because also need to check for NaN.

Comment: @EldarAgalarov Good catch. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Improvements on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59124029/3881993):

1. `BigDecimal.floatValue()` is not expected to return `Float.NaN` since there is no `BigDecimal.NaN`.
2. `String.valueOf(float)` —or `Float.toString(float)` to be precise— switches to scientific notation if *number* < 10<sup>-3</sup> or *number* ≥ 10<sup>7</sup>, which causes `new BigDecimal(String)` to fail.

```java
public static float floatValueExact(BigDecimal decimal) {
    float result = decimal.floatValue();
    if (Float.isInfinite(result) || new BigDecimal(result).compareTo(decimal) != 0) {
        throw new ArithmeticException(decimal + " cannot be represented as float");
    }
    return result;
}
```